# Best way to define a method which can accept an Action or a Func delegate

Tags: c#

I would like to introduce a method/function which can receive an `Action` or a `Func<T>`, and depending on what it got, it should return `void` or `T`.

Now I have to write this method in two, almost same versions like this.

```
public void WrapAction(Action action) {
  // do something...
  action();
  // do something more...
}

public T WrapFunc(Func<T> func) {
  // do something...
  var result = func();
  // do something more...
  return result;
}
```

Is there any technique to avoid this repetition?

In contrast, for example in Javascript I have the flexibility to accept any kind of a function (may be `void`) and just return it's result, and if it was `void`, then it will return `undefined`. But in C# one cannot write something like `Func<void>`.

Comment: Extract the repeating bit out to a separate private method (or methods) might be a good way to go.... depending on what you are doing.

Comment: Yes, it can make things nicer generally. Currently I'm wrapping the delegates in a `try...catch` with some common exception handling. Anyway my question was rather a theoretical one than a practical.

Comment: Type unsafe? Use `object` and cast it to needed type. You can use e.g. `if(myobj is Action)`. Type safe? Use generics for type safety (but usage is very limited).

Comment: @Sinatr yes I was thinking about that, but I wouldn't like to completely give up type safety if there is any way.

Comment: Look for examples in the Framework and you'll indeed find that they have to have all of the separate methods, over and over.

Comment: Thank you all for the tips and answers, I chose @rboe's answer, even if that technique might have a slight performance overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about to make an `Func<bool>` out of an action via an extension method and reduce the wrapper to handle `Func<T>` only.

```
public static class ActionExtensions
{
    public static Func<bool> ToFunc(this Action action)
    {
        return () =>
        {
            action();
            return true;
        };
    }
}
```

Then `WrapAction` could simply call `WrapFunc`.

```
public void WrapAction(Action action)
{
    WrapFunc(action.ToFunc());
}
```

Or remove `WrapAction` at all and use `WrapFunc` directly.

```
WrapFunc(action.ToFunc());
```

Comment: I like this, the type argument is not even needed I think, it could return simply `null` for example.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási: Nice idea - no need to have a generic type T. I simplified it by using bool. The post has been edited.

Comment: Sorry I've just edited my comment and suggest to use rather `null` because `true` and `false` has a "meaning". Obviously it doesn't matter too much.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási: I thought of returning true, because the action has been executed. But this does not change the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is that you can extract the repeating bits out to separate methods in the same class so, something like this...

```
public void WrapAction(Action action) {
  DoInitialBit();
  action();
  DoFinalBit();
}

public T WrapFunc(Func<T> func) {
  DoInitialBit();
  var result = func();
  DoFinalBit();
  return result;
}

private void DoInitialBit()
{
    // Do the thing before you call the Action or Func
}

private void DoFinalBit()
{
    // Do the thing after you call the Action or Func
}
```

Obviously, you may have to take inputs or return outputs from these additional methods as required but that's the general gist of it.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to go this way I think as it seems like there is no special technique for these cases.

Answer (score 1):

Some really ugly code to have code DRY:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var p = new Program();
    p.WrapAction(() => Console.WriteLine(123));
    Console.WriteLine(p.WrapFunc<string>(() => "321"));
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public void WrapAction(Action action) => WrapActionInner<object>(action);

public T WrapFunc<T>(Func<T> func) => WrapActionInner<T>(func);

private T WrapActionInner<T>(object action)
{
    if (action is Action)
    {
        ((Action)action)();
        return default(T);
    }
    return ((Func<T>)action)();
}
```

The idea is to wrap functionality into type unsafe private method.

Comment: This is technically similar to @rboe's answer, but sintactically I like that better. By the way I don't think this is ugly code, it's *technical* code.